# How to set up phpmailer?

Tags: email, phpmailer

I'd like to use phpmailer for sending emails, but, as far as I can see, it requires me to point out SMTP server. Since I don't know it, is there a way to just use it without configuring for that or maybe there are other plugins for the job?

Comment: so how do you expect to be able to send mail if you don't know which server to use? that's rather like going "I wanna mail a letter, but don't know where the mailbox is, can I just leave the letter sitting on the road?"

Comment: Well I'm used to using mail(); function, but, for reasons unknown, this time that function is sending everything right in to the spam folder (even though I've defined headers). Anyhow, I'll try using the localhost thing, see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not spamming the things.

If the mail is going-in to junk folder, this does not means that the your mail() function is not working. It has something to do with spam control activity done by mail reciever domain.

And in case you doing it for a valid purpose try signing your mail with dk/dkim signature and provide a SPF record to your domain.

Comment: make sure not to send too many mails to same domain, they might blacklist your IP too ;-)